# On my Toshiba I want OpenGL 3.2, but the graphic card reports it's incompatible?

Tags: opengl, drivers, graphics

We have a computer graphics project and we need to use opengl 3.1 or above versions with the shaders.

I have toshiba a200 with ati radeon hd 2600 graphic card. my friends with same graphic cards but different brand notebook could update and run opengl 3.1. However when I tried to install the driver from the amd website, I got this error

```
"ATI Catalyst Mobility cannot be downloaded due to incompatable hardware/software on your computer. Your computer does not contain a proper graphics adapter."
```

Do you know any solutions? If I bought a notebook with same devices but not a Toshiba, I probably could start my work...

Comment: Is there a way to install amd's driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you can't install the generic graphics drivers for your card from the graphics OEM that means you have to get the newest driver from your PC manufacturer. I had this issue with an ATi 9200 Mobility ages ago on an old Sony VAIO. The ATi driver would not install unless I downloaded the "special" driver from Sony's support site.

Comment: Toshiba moved A series notebooks to archive, so I dont think they will release a new driver.

Answer (score 1):

You should confirm that is the actual graphics card your friend is using. According to [AMD's specifications](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-2000/hd-2600/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-2600-gpu-specs.aspx), it's compatible up to OpenGL 3.1.

> OpenGL 3.1 support

Comment: Those specs are for the desktop cards, not the "Mobility Radeon" notebook GPUs.